# What happens when you run rake:db seed twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, seed

I'm new to rails and I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this question.

Let's say I have

```
Project.create!([{title: "foo", description: "bar"}])
```

in my seeds.rb file and then run

```
$rake db:seed
```

twice. Would there be two near-identical entries in the database or would it override the initial entry?

Comment: Why don´t you run it twice and check it on db?

Comment: @Doguita I've got a lot of non-seed data on the database which took a while to put in there. I don't want to have to drop the db if something goes wrong. Also, I thought it would be good for people like me (read: noobs) to be able to find an answer without having to potentially screw around with their databases.

Comment: I understand. But when I have this kind of question I just create a new rails app and do some tests.

Comment: @Doguita that's actually a good idea; I could just use a new test app for these sorts of problems. I'll do that in future - thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will duplicate.

If you want to run multiple times, but prevent duplication. I guess you could:

1. Use validation in one key field like putting `validate_uniqueness_of :key_attribute`
2. Test the count of your table like:

   `MyClass.create if MyClass.count == 0`
3. **Better solution** might be to use `find_or_create_by` method. See the docs: http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/03/24/using-find-or-create-with-multiple-attributes/

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for. And nice advice on the uniqueness validation. Wish I could upvote you, but sadly I'm still sub 15 rep. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

It just runs the file. Rails does nothing for you, as far as preventing creation of duplicate seed data. If your file creates a record, it will attempt to create that record each time you seed. It's completely up to you to prevent this, in the case that you don't want duplicate seed data.

If you want to create a record unless it already exists, use `find_or_create_by`:

```
Project.find_or_create_by_title_and_description "foo", "bar"
```

This will create a `Project` with the given title and description unless it already exists, letting you run `rake db:seed` as many times as you want without creating duplicates.

Comment: VoA, take a look at meagar's solution also. I guess it's cleaner and should solve your problem. I'll edit mine to complete the information.

Comment: Good to know. I would have thought there was some sort of rails magic which might prevent or mess with the basic execution of the ruby in seeds.rb but it actually makes it easier to deal with without such hidden code. Thanks!

Comment: @VoA Rails can't assume that it's appropriate for only one unique record to be created. Your seed file might create 50 fake "posts" each time it's run, and you might want to create 250 fake posts by running it 5 times.

Comment: Also in Rails 4, it is find_or_create_by which accepts a hash.